# SSIS - How to Insert from Flat File to OLE DB with date range?

Tags: while-loop, ssis, dataflowtask, flatfilesource, oledbdestination

I have a flat file source with columns that have start and end dates per row, and the table I am attempting to insert into only has one date column, which means I have to insert 1 row per week from the start date until the end date.

Sample FF Source:
Col1,StartDate,EndDate,Col4
1234,7/10/2018,28/10/2018,1.000

Rows to be inserted into table: 
+------+------------+-------+
| Col1 |    Date    | Col4  |
+------+------------+-------+
| 1234 | 7/10/2018  | 1.000 |
| 1234 | 14/10/2018 | 1.000 |
| 1234 | 21/10/2018 | 1.000 |
| 1234 | 28/10/2018 | 1.000 |
+------+------------+-------+

Comment: What have you done so far? I suggest you load the file as is into a staging table then join to a calendar table and insert into the final table.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Right now I have an FF source > Data Conv > Lookup - to check if the rows from the ff exist on the db, if not, go to No Match Output, which is: > (task in question)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would take Nicks suggestion and implement:

```
--This just replicates your load to a staging table
declare @t table (Col1 int,StartDate date,EndDate date,Col4 money)
insert into @t
values
(1234,'10/7/2018','10/28/2018',1.000)

--This will be your insert into final
select Col1,EndDate as [Date],Col4
from @t 

union all

select t.Col1,a.Date,t.col4
from @t t
cross apply (select * 
             from dDate 
             where [Date] >= t.StartDate --This includes start date
                 and [Date] < t.EndDate --This does not include ED, I did this to avoid result not ending on same day of the week
                 and [WeekDay] = datepart(dw,t.StartDate) --Weekly records starting on SD and progressing weekly
            )a
order by 1,2 -- Just for your viewing pleasure
```

Results:

```
Col1    Date        Col4
1234    2018-10-07  1.00
1234    2018-10-14  1.00
1234    2018-10-21  1.00
1234    2018-10-28  1.00
```

This assumes you have a DateDimension or "Calendar Table" with fields Date (representing the calendar date) and Weekday (Representing the numerical value of day of the week).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a separate answer on how to do it in SSIS using a script task:

1. In Data Flow add a source reading your flat file
2. Add a Script component and select transformation (connect to source)
3. Go to input and select all inputs as read only
4. Go to input/output and add a new output and call it New
5. Add your new columns Col1,Date,Column (with data types)
6. Go to script and enter it and paste in the following code

   ```
   public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
   {
       int daysToAdd = 0;
       DateTime SD = Row.StartDate;

       while (SD.AddDays(daysToAdd) < Row.EndDate)
       {
           NewBuffer.AddRow();
           NewBuffer.Col1 = Row.Col1;
           NewBuffer.Date = SD.AddDays(daysToAdd);
           NewBuffer.Column = Row.Col4;

           daysToAdd = daysToAdd + 7;
       }

       //Add the end date
       NewBuffer.AddRow();
       NewBuffer.Col1 = Row.Col1;
       NewBuffer.Date = Row.EndDate;
       NewBuffer.Column = Row.Col4;

   }
   ```

You will now have a new output called "New" that transformed your single line into weekly rows between start and end dates.